# Will Convert(Bigint) Allow Calculations on String

Tags: sql-server

I always have trouble attempting such.  I found this as a solution, but I was curious if their was a better way of doing such.

```
declare @CountByZip as int
select @CountByZip = convert(decimal(18,4),count(HouseNumbers))
from zipcodeDB
Where zip is not null
```

And using this as the statement executes no problem!

```
Convert(decimal(18,4),Count(case when zip IN ('123', '456', '789') then zip else null end))/@CountByZip
```

However, I was curious if there was a way to convert to int in my case statement and allow that to remove the creation of the variable and select statement at the top of my example.

```
Convert(Bigint,Convert(decimal(18,4),Count(case when zip IN ('123', '456', '789') then zip else null end))/Count(Zip)
```

However, this returns the dreaded SQL error of 
'Error converting data type varchar to numeric'
which is what made me switch to my declare statement at the top.

Is it possible to perform my 2nd example?

Comment: All these `converts` don't make sense. I don't think you need any `convert` at all. Try the simple expression without any `converts` and tell us what problem you have with it.

Comment: The convert I use here is so that it will display a decimal, 'Convert(decimal(18,4),Count(case when zip IN ('123', '456', '789') then zip else null end))/@CountByZip' is there a better way to have a decimal displayed?

Comment: I don't understand what you want and what is your problem. Try to explain in other words what is your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something like this

```
cast(count(case when zip in ('123', '456', '789') then zip else null end)*1/whateveryourdividingby as decimal(10,4))
```